# How does "Lead us not into temptation" need to be interpreted?

Tags: life-of-jesus, nature-of-god, prayer, terminology, temptation

When we Christians recite the "Our Father", we always say:

> ... and lead us not into temptation ...

From this quote I understand very clearly that God can lead us to temptation thus contradicting whatever else is present in the Gospel.

I read in different forums that such sentence must be interpreted as of "permitting" to fall into temptation. However I believe all words have a meaning and in this case "lead" has its own [definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lead). 
Appealing to interpretation sounds like cheating to me and I don't see why we should do it but to "make things work".

So how to deal with this sentence and solve such dilemma?

Comment: This might be good for Biblical Hermeneutics StackExchange. Or you can ask for a specific denomination's viewpoint on the subject

Comment: Please don't edit your question to make it less likely to be reopened.  Having a question closed doesn't mean it is a bad question, just that it probably can't be objectively answered here.

Comment: the actually is another closed wueation asked recently you might want to look at https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/61316/why-the-wrongness-of-our-father-translation-wasnt-spotted-earlier

Comment: and it has been asked on the hermeneutics site already https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/why-pray-lead-us-not-into-temptation

Answer (score 3):

The word *lead* is nearly as unambiguous in Greek as it is in English -  εἰσφέρω (*eispherō*) - and the word for temptation - πειρασμός (*peirasmos*) - can mean temptation towards evil, just as in English.  It should be noted, though, that whereas in the preceding verse - *forgive us our debts* (Matthew 6:12), or *forgive us our sins* (Luke 11:4) - the Evangelists write in the imperative mood in Greek (i.e. as a sort of command), both Matthew and Luke use the subjunctive mood in the following verse.  What we normally see as *lead us not into temptation* could just as well be rendered *may you not lead us into temptation*, or perhaps *may you* never *lead us into temptation*.

While one might be tempted [sorry] to read a meaning of "test" rather than "tempt" into *peirasmos*, I don't think this is the best approach here.  Instead, one should probably also see *and lead us not into temptation* in opposition to the other clause in the verse, *but deliver us from evil* (or *the evil one* - the Greek can be read either way and was).

In his lengthly sermon on just this verse, Cyril of Alexandria - a 4th century Greek speaking to Greeks - explained:

> There is a certain close connection in the clauses: for plainly it follows from men not being led into temptation, that they are also delivered from evil; or perchance, were any one to say, that the not being led into it is the same as the being delivered from it, he would not err from the truth.<sup>1</sup>

In other words, Cyril is saying that the way to understand the verse is that it is a supplication to God to deliver one from evil in general and not - "God forbid" one might add - into temptation.

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sup>*Commentary on the Gospel According to Luke*, [Sermon LXXVII](http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/cyril_on_luke_07_sermons_66_80.htm#SERMON%20LXXVII.)</sup>

Comment: The word "lead" is not ambiguous in all languages... I wrote in English so that everybody understands.

Comment: I don't think I said it was ambiguous - just the opposite.